# Angular RxJs: Request for each item in array

Tags: angular

One of my components gets an array of items. Each item has a permission, which will be checked by a rest call based on the user role. If the user is permitted for the item, it can be displayed.

So I came along with this approach:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  for( let tile of this.tiles ) {
    this.permissionCheckService.isUserPermitted( tile.name ).subscribe( 
      isPermitted => tile.show = isPermitted
    )
  }
}
```

**But this solution introduces a new variable "show". Maybe it would be even better if the items, which should not be displayed, will be removed from the array?**

Next step should be to implement a loading indicator. This indicator should be removed, if all requests are finished. But my problems starts here. I think I have to combine all observables, but i don't know how to do it.

Here is a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wfjj5n-horatl?embed=1&file=src/app/alert-basic.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hiding/showing the loading indicator can be done with one simple boolean flag that's set to true/false on the beginning/completion of the stream. For that, of course, you need to have *one* stream, so `forkJoin` or `combineLatest` are your friends. Also, you can put the result array in a separate stream, to keep with the reactive/immutable paradigm. Something like

```
  constructor(private permissionCheckService: PermissionCheckService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.isLoading = true;

    this.shownTiles$ = this.checkPermissions().pipe(
      map(this.filterTiles),
      tap(() => (this.isLoading = false))
    );
  }

  checkPermissions = (): Observable<boolean[]> =>
    forkJoin(
      this.tiles.map(tile =>
        this.permissionCheckService.isUserPermitted(tile.name)
      )
    );

  filterTiles = (booleanFlagsArr: boolean[]): any[] =>
    this.tiles.filter((tile, index) => booleanFlagsArr[index] === true);
```

Here's a stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wfjj5n-f7aht4?file=src%2Fapp%2Falert-basic.ts

Comment: thank you very much, great answer! But I have forgotton one detail. Not every item must have a permission. For items which don't have any permission, the service shouldn't be called. I've forked your stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wfjj5n-jkhre6?embed=1&file=src/app/alert-basic.ts . Also I've added the new param "permission" to a tile. Maybe you can help me again?

Answer (score 0):

Yopu can use forkJoin to subscribe to an array of calls. Then filter by response

```
forkJoin(
  this.tiles.map(x => this.permissionCheckService.isUserPermitted(x.name))
).subscribe((res: any[]) => {
  //if you want store in an auxiliar variable
  this.tilesValid = this.tiles.filter((x, index) => res[index]);
  //or
  //this.tiles = this.tiles.filter((x, index) => res[index]);
});
```